# After entered correct login data Logcat shows login error

Tags: php, android

After entered correct data in LoginActivity.java app doesn't go to the next activity, progress bar is constantly loading and Logcat shows me this **"login":[],"success":"0","message":"error"** when I use **Log.d** in Response it's looks like I insert incorrect data, but I'm sure it's correct. I can't find where the problem is, I'm still learning.

Below is a snippet of code:

```
  private void Login(final String email, final String password){
    loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    btn_login.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_LOGIN,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        String success = jsonObject.getString("success");
                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("login");

                        if(success.equals("1")){
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){

                                JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                String name = object.getString("name").trim();
                                String email = object.getString("email").trim();

                                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("name", name);
                                intent.putExtra("email", email);
                                startActivity(intent);

                                loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        btn_login.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error " +e.toString(), 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    Log.d(TAG, "Info" + response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    btn_login.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error " +error.toString(), 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })
```

Login.php

```
    <?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    require_once 'conn.php';
    $sql = "Select * from firmy where email='$email'";

    $response = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $result = array();
    $result['login'] = array();
    json_encode($response);

    if ( mysqli_num_rows($response) === 1 ){
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($response);
        if (password_verify($password, $row['password'])){
            $index['name'] = $row['name'];
            $index['email'] = $row['email'];
            array_push($result['login'], $index);
            $result['success'] = "1";
            $result['message'] = "success";
            echo json_encode($result);
            mysqli_close($conn);

            }else {
            $result['success'] = "0";
            $result['message'] = "error";
            echo json_encode($result);
            mysqli_close($conn);
      }  
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You need far more information here, like what server is returning this error

Comment: It won't go to the `HomeActivity` because the `success` is returning 0 instead of 1. Mostly, your request payload is empty. Where are you sending the email and password to the server?

Comment: @SrikarReddy Email and password are sending to MySQL.

Comment: What is the format the server is expecting and what is the format you are sending it?

Answer (score 1):

[StringRequest](https://github.com/google/volley/blob/master/src/main/java/com/android/volley/toolbox/StringRequest.java) is used for `GET` requests and to make `POST` requests, use [JsonObjectRequest](https://github.com/google/volley/blob/ddbc32c04921df0973baadeee50f8d3099b12e14/src/main/java/com/android/volley/toolbox/JsonObjectRequest.java).

Sample Post Request that sends username and password to the server.

```
private void login(final String email, final String password) {
    loadingBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    loginButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject.put("username", email);
        jsonObject.put("password", password);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    final JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_LOGIN,
            jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                String success = response.getString("success");
                JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("login");

                if (success.equals("1")) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        String name = object.getString("name").trim();
                        String email = object.getString("email").trim();

                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                                MainActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("name", name);
                        intent.putExtra("email", email);
                        startActivity(intent);

                        loadingBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                loadingBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                loginButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error " + e.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "Info" + response);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
            loadingBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            loginButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error " + error.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            return params;
        }
    };

    // Make the request
    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

Comment: I have this request in my code:
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

Comment: What is the type of `stringRequest` variable? Is it or `StringRequest` or `JsonObjectRequest`?

Comment: It's StringRequest.

Comment: Can you use `JsonObjectRequest` as shown in the above example?

Comment: Value<br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject but I don't know what I should change in PHP because I've never used JsonObjectRequest

Answer (score 0):

it's seem your login operation not succeeded. as you got 0 for success **"login":[],"success":"0","message":"error"**
where you should got **"success":"1"**.
so, i guess you need to check you data again.

and here a few points I will recommended for you,they will help you while dealing with APIs

1. always check you API request/response using [POSTMAN](https://www.getpostman.com/)
2. use model to represent your response instead of `JSONObject` ,`JSONArray`,..ext.
3. use an easy & customized http/https library. & i will recommended [this one](https://github.com/clickapps-android/app-api)

happy coding